# Laravel www to non www not working woth folder redirection

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have setup code in htaccess File. to redirect https://www.website.com/ to https://website.com/  but both link are working as same.

```
SetEnv PHPRC /home/customer/www/website.com/public_html/php.ini
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.website.com [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://website.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

  # Disable Directory listing
Options -Indexes


# block files which needs to be hidden, specify .example extension of the file
<Files ~ "\.(env|json|config.js|md|gitignore|gitattributes|lock)$">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Cache-Control "private"
</IfModule>
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php80 .php .php5 .php4 .php3
```

Comment: Move `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]` below `R=301` line and retest after clearing browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

1. http to https
2. www to non www

Comment: Instead of what? The OPs directives are simply in the wrong order (as mentioned in the comment above, below th question). You can't _remove_ the rewrite to `public/` otherwise I suspect the site will break.